# Why won't this DOM element disappear?

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a page that uses jQuery with a small glitch.

I managed to get this down to a simple example that demonstrates the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideIt()
{
    $('#hideme').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); } );
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='#hideme'>Hide me!</div>
<button onclick='hideIt();'>Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you would expect, the problem is simple: the caption doesn't disappear.

What simple thing did I overlook? (Or if it's not a simple thing, what complicated thing did I miss?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the `#` in `<div id='#hideme'>Hide me!</div>` :)

Comment: It's small stuff like that where it's so easy to overlook - it's good to lend it a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: Thanks man. I got so used to using # for selecting that I just absent-mindedly typed it in the id attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The selector is not finding your div, because you have an `#` character on it:

Change:

```
<div id='#hideme'>Hide me!</div>
```

To:

```
<div id='hideme'>Hide me!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but James beat you to the answer, so I gave the best answer to him. +1 for finding it though.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the div should be "`hideme`" not "`#hideme`"

Comment: This is the same as what was mentioned above in the other answers.